# Webpack bundle Angular 4 service

Tags: angular, webpack

I have an angular 4 app that I am working on converting to webpack from systemjs.

I have an angular service named config.service.ts and it is imported with a line you can see below.

```
Unexpected token (17:14)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import { ConfigService } from './services/config.service';
```

It appears that webpack is trying to find a loader that would work for .service files but this is just a typescript file.

Is there a way to configure webpack to load these files correctly?

webpack.config.ts:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
entry: {
    'polyfills': './app/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './app/vendor.ts',
    'app': './app/app.component.ts'
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: '/\.ts$/',
            loaders: [
                {
                    loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    options: { configFileName: './tsconfig.json' }
                }, 'angular2-template-loader'
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader'
            ]
        }
    ]
}
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

error message after changing webpack.config.js to enter at main.ts instead of app.component.ts:

```
ERROR in ./app/app.module.ts
Module parse failed: <path omitted>\app.module.ts Unexpected token (72:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| // Routes should be listed in the order of most specific to least specific
| const appRoutes: Routes = [
|     //{ path: '/', component: MainPageComponent },
|     //{ path: 'alerts', component: AlertsPageComponent }
 @ ./app/main.ts 2:0-41
```

These paths don't actually do anything yet, its on my to-do list. I tried removing the code and it just moves the error down to the next import.

app.module.ts

```
// imports omitted

enableProdMode();

// UI Component imports
import {
    // importing a bunch of primeng components
} from 'primeng/primeng';

import { NgSemanticModule } from 'ng-semantic/ng-semantic';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
// other component imports omitted

// Routes should be listed in the order of most specific to least specific
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    //{ path: '/', component: MainPageComponent },
    //{ path: 'alerts', component: AlertsPageComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([]),
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        // other imports omitted for length
    ],
    declarations: [
        // omitted
    ],
    providers: [
        // services listed here
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can you show your webpack.config.js file? Do you have a `resolve: [ 'ts','js']` block?

Comment: Added my webpack.config.ts above. Yes, I do have a resolve block. I tried adding .service.ts, .service, etc to see if that might help but it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Its hard to say, but seems like your 'ts' files are not being processed through your loaders - which is why its complaining about Typescript. In the end Webpack only really understands javascript. It could have something to do with your tsconfig.json file, could you post that too?

Comment: Added my tsconfig.json.

Comment: Not sure what is the root cause, but in my webpack config for ts loader. I didn't add the options one. It looks like that only `loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']`
And one comment, the entry of `'app': './app/app.component.ts'` seems not correct. It should point to the `main.ts` file instead, the one which used to bootstrap the app.

Comment: i was just going to say the same thing ... should be using main.ts as the app entry

Comment: switching to main.ts seems to have fixed the issue with config.service.ts (or webpack hasnt gotten to it yet) but now im seeing a similar issue with app.module.ts. Added error message above.

Comment: Is this possible that you can share the source code with us?

Comment: added most of the code from app.module.ts